# end event is not fired when piping to stream transformer

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

In the following code the `end` event of read stream is fired properly.

```
const frs = createReadStream("./file.txt", {
  encoding: "utf8"
});

frs
  .on("data", chunk => {
    console.log(chunk);
  })
  .on("error", err => {
    throw err;
  })
  .on("end", () => {
    doSomething()
  });
```

But why the `end` event is not fired when piping to `Transform` streams.

```
frs
  .pipe(transform1)
  .pipe(transform2)
  .on("error", err => {
    throw err;
  })
  .on("end", () => {
    doSomething()
  });
```

In the second case (piping) how to call `doSomething` when stream is ended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform actions in 'finish' event.

Just replace 'end' on 'finish'

```
frs
.pipe(transform1)
.pipe(transform2)
.on("error", err => {
  throw err;
})
.on("finish", () => {
  doSomething()
});
```